# Searching for index values after button click

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a game for a school project and I have a 2d array of ImageButtons, I want to know if I can get the array's indexes for the button I clicked without having to do 100 cases or run in a loop 100 times (10x10 board)

Comment: If you are in a listener, the event's source is a reference to the button that was clicked. Add the button's x & y to the client Properties for the button when it is created and added to the array. Or extend the button class and save the x&y in your class. cast the source from the event to your class and call its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to tag each ImageButton with its array indices. For example if you create these buttons in code using a loop, you can use the loop variables to set the tags as you go. For example:

```
imgButton1.setTag("1|1");
imgButton2.setTag("1|2");
...
imgButton10.setTag("1|10");
imgButton11.setTag("2|1");
etc
```

If your ImageButtons are pre-defined in XML, you can do the same with:

```
android:tag="1|1"
```

Then in your ImageButton clickhandler (I assume you'll attach the same one to all the buttons):

```
String tag = (String) view.getTag();
```

Then substring out the two indexes.